# How do I delete a widget in OrbTk?

Tags: rust

I was able to make a basic GUI with a label and a button using the development version of OrbTk (not the one on crates.io). Now, I want to delete the label and button when that button is clicked.

I've looked at the examples on GitHub, and the documentation for OrbTk on docs.rs but the widgets do not seem to have a function `delete()` or `remove()` except for the Grid.

So I put the widgets in a grid hoping I could clear the whole grid by executing `grid.clear()`. 
But now in my code the function `clear()` doesn't seem to exist...

It is written in [the documentation](https://docs.rs/orbtk/0.2.27/orbtk/layouts/struct.Grid.html#method.clear) though.

Code:

```
use orbtk::*;

widget!(MainView);

//MainView
impl Template for MainView {
    fn template(self, _: Entity, ctx: &mut BuildContext) -> Self {
        self.name("MainView").child(
            Grid::create()
                .columns(
                    Columns::create()
                        .column("*").build()
                )
                .rows(
                    Rows::create().row("*").row("*").build()
                )
                .child(
                    TextBlock::create()
                        .text("Label A!")
                        .attach(Grid::row(0))
                        .build(ctx),
                )
                .child(
                    Button::create()
                        .text("My button")
                        .attach(Grid::row(1))
                        .on_click(move |_states, _| -> bool {
                            println!("Rofl");

                            true
                        })
                        .build(ctx),
                )
            .build(ctx)
        )
    }
}

fn main() {
      Application::new()
        .window(|ctx| {
            Window::create()
                .title("OrbTk - minimal example")
                .position((100.0, 100.0))
                .size(420.0, 730.0)
                .child(MainView::create().build(ctx))
                .build(ctx)
        })
        .run();
}
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "orb_tk"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["Niel"]
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
orbtk = { git = "https://github.com/redox-os/orbtk.git", branch= "develop" }
```

Seems like in the new development version of OrbTk I'm using the `Grid` doesn't have a `remove()` or `clear()` function anymore. No I have no clue at all on how to delete a widget.

How can I delete a widget or a group of widgets in OrbTk?

Comment: The documentation you linked to is for an older version of orb_tk (0.2.27), whereas you're depending on the develop branch of the Git repo. You could use `cargo doc` to review the documentation for the actual version that you're pulling in.

Comment: @djc Already done that. The version I'm using doesn't have a clear() or remove() function.